# When players leave in a public game, will new ones ever join?

Tags: diablo-iii

When playing in a public game, sometimes players leave and I never see anyone new join. Even when a new major quest starts new players won't appear.

Do public games have a high entropy rate in the sense that, once a player leaves no new ones will join?

Answer (score 1):

They *can* join, but they might not depending on how busy the servers are. It's almost as annoying as jumping into a two-player game with someone who spends 10 minutes in town then logs off :(

In my experience, it's quicker to jump out and hit "public" again. Hopefully they'll add a more comprehensive LFG-style interface, but for now we're stuck with the current situation.

Comment: The problem with jumping out and back in again, is that you can only select the start of the quest as your entry point.